# Git rebase does not deletes files in feature branch

Tags: git, github, rebase

I created two branches **b1 and b2** based on **dev** branch on a same day. Both branch have file named **f1.txt**.

After 1 day, I did a commit (**c1**) deleting file f1.txt in branch b1 and pushed the changes to remote **branch b1** and merged it to **dev**.

After 1 month I worked on a **branch b2** , made a commit **(c2)** and did (**git pull origin/dev --rebase**). I mostly do (**git pull --rebase**)

The file **f1.txt** is still there in **branch b2**.

How can we update local branch in case of file deletion in **branch b2** ?

Answer (score 0):

#### First you must understand rebase completely

Rebase doesn't work with *files*.  Rebase works with *commits*.  Specifically, `git rebase` means:

- I have some commits.
- A lot of stuff about these commits is good.
- But some things about these commits is not so good.
- I know it's impossible to *change* an *existing commit*, but if you, Git, would be so kind, I'd like you to take each of these existing commits and apply them, one by one, starting somewhere I'd like, and giving me the option to stop and *change the files around and/or change the commit message* **before** you make the new copy.

That is, we take some existing series of commits:

```
          K--L   <-- my-feature (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H--I--J   <-- main
```

and, because we don't like the fact that the *parent commit* of `K` is `H`—these two commits are in the wrong place in the graph, in other words—we run:

```
git rebase main
```

and Git will take commits `K` and `L` and *copy* them to *new* commits.  The new commits will:

- do the same thing as `K` and `L`, but
- come after `J`

so that we get:

```
          K--L   <-- my-feature
         /
...--G--H--I--J   <-- main
               \
                K'-L'  <-- new-and-improved-my-feature
```

Note how both branches co-exist at this point.

Now we make use of the fact that *humans* (though not Git) *find* commits by using a *branch name*.  (Git uses hash IDs.)  Commits `K'` and `L'` look a lot like `K` and `L`, and a human looking at `L'` will probably mistakenly think they are looking at `L`.  (*Git* won't, because `L'` will have a totally different random-looking hash ID.)

So now, we have Git swap the names around a bit!  Then we have Git check out the new branch it built:

```
          K--L   <-- old-and-lousy-my-feature
         /
...--G--H--I--J   <-- main
               \
                K'-L'  <-- my-feature (HEAD)
```

and then *delete the name* on the old branch:

```
          K--L   [abandoned
         /
...--G--H--I--J   <-- main
               \
                K'-L'  <-- my-feature (HEAD)
```

We won't be able to find commits `K-L` any more, because *we* use names.  (Git can still find them, as long as Git can find the hash IDs.  Git keeps those hash IDs around for a while, or on GitHub, forever.)

That's rebase in a nutshell, though we can get fancy using `git rebase -i` for instance.  Here Git will put up an instruction sheet with `pick` commands, which we can modify to read `edit` or `reword` or whatever.  This changes how Git does the copying-of-commits.  Before we go any further, we should mention that the actual *copying* happens through `git cherry-pick`.<sup>1</sup>  The way cherry-pick "copies a commit" is, roughly speaking, to compare the commit's snapshot against the commit's parent's snapshot.  Whatever *changes* this commit makes, those are the changes the copy will make, too.

Thus, in our example above, the *change* (the `git diff` output) you'll see if you show commit `K`—if you do this before rebasing, or if you save its hash ID so that you can pick it out after rebasing—will match the *change* that you'll see if you show commit `K'` after rebasing.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is true for all interactive `git rebase` operations, and for most `git rebases` in *modern* Git, but in Git before version 2.26, a lot of rebase operations used a different back-end.  The result is *usually* the same, and you should generally think of rebase as "automated cherry-pick" anyway.

---

#### Next you must understand `git pull` completely

The `pull` command is basically a convenience command: it just runs two *other* Git commands for you.  This makes it relatively easy to understand, except that to really understand it, you must understand both of the other two commands!  So let's see what they are:

1. First, `git pull` runs `git fetch`.

   The `git fetch` command means *reach out to some other Git repository and collect some commit(s) from it if and as needed*.  This can get complicated, so let's leave it at this for now.  The new commits that `git fetch` picks up, if any, get recorded in a special file in the hidden `.git` folder: `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.  Depending on your Git version and how you invoke `git pull`, this `git fetch` can also update things like `origin/dev`.  But in all cases, this *does not affect any of your current work*.

   New commits, stuffed into your Git repository, are simply new commits.  You aren't actually *using* any of them yet.  Usually, we fetch new commits because we *want to use them*.  So...
2. Having run `git fetch`, `git pull` runs a second Git command.

   This second command is up to you.  You can choose to have Git run `git merge`—that's the default, if you haven't set anything else up—or you can choose to have Git run `git rebase`.

   The purpose of this second command is, of course, to make use of the new commits you fetched in step 1.  This is where everything gets pretty tricky though.

We'll get back to `git fetch` in a moment as it is about to matter a lot.  Let's take a look now at the information you have provided.

#### What you said

> I created two branches **b1 and b2** based on **dev** branch on a same day.
> Both branch have file named **f1.txt**.

This isn't *quite* the right description.  Let's correct it.

Since Git is really about *commits*—not files, not branches, but *commits*—let's draw the situation you've described so far.  You had a repository, which has some set of commits.  Each commit holds a full snapshot of every file, plus some metadata (things like who made the commit and when, and the raw hash ID of the commit's *parent* commit).  We'll draw this set of commits and the branch names, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev, b1, b2
```

That is, all three branch names select some commit.  Each commit has a unique hash ID—some big ugly string of letters and digits, unique to that one particular commit—and a *branch name* gives a way for a human to tell Git: *Just get me the latest commit, whatever its hash ID is.*  Git does this by storing the latest commit's hash ID in the branch name.  So the three branch names here, `dev`, `b1`, and `b2` all store the hash ID of commit `H`.  Commit `H` stores, in its snapshot, the full set of files including file `f1.txt`; commit `H` stores, in its metadata, the hash ID of earlier (parent) commit `G`.

Since all three *branch names* hold the *same hash ID*, all three branches select commit `H`.  That one commit holds file `f1.txt`, and it will do so forever (no part of any commit can ever change).

> After 1 day, I did a commit (**c1**) deleting file **f1.txt** in branch **b1**

Let's draw commit `C1` (I'll even call it `C1` here):

```
          C1   <-- b1
         /
...--G--H   <-- dev, b2
```

Commit `C1` has a new snapshot: in `C1`'s snapshot, file `f1.txt` doesn't exist.  That's a full snapshot of every file, so when we compare the snapshot in `H` to the snapshot in `C1`, one of the *changes* we see is "delete file `f1.txt`".

Note that `C1` does not *store changes*.  It just stores a snapshot plus metadata.  The "change" we see is a result of comparing `H` vs `C1`, as obtained by following branch name `dev` or `b2` to commit `H`, and following branch name `b2` to `C1`.

> and pushed the changes to remote branch **b1** and merged it to **dev**.

I presume this means: *I ran `git push origin b1`* or *I ran `git push -u origin b1`*.  So far so good, but now, we have a bit of a problem.  When you use `git push`, you are doing the closest thing there is to the opposite of `git fetch`.  You have your Git call up some other Git software, that is working with a different but related Git repository—what Git calls a *clone*.  You probably cloned your repository from theirs, but "clone-ness" is symmetric: if Fred2 is a clone of Fred1, then Fred1 is a clone of Fred2.

The thing here is that each clone has *its own branches*.  That's why you said "remote branch **b1**": that's a branch named `b1` over on `origin`.  So now *they* have a `b1`.  Then you say *and merged it to `dev`*, but what is *it* here?  How did you do this merge?

Given that you have your own `dev and your own` b1`, you might have run:

```
git checkout dev; git merge b1
```

Or, given that you tagged this whole thing with [[image]github](/questions/tagged/github), maybe you mean that after:

```
git push -u origin b1
```

you used a green clicky button *on* GitHub to cause the merge to happen *in the GitHub repository over on GitHub*.  That is, you did the merging in *their* repository, without affecting *your* repository.

I don't know which of these might be right, but if we assume you used the button on GitHub for now, and did nothing locally, your *local* repository now has this:

```
          C1   <-- b1, origin/b1
         /
...--G--H   <-- dev, b2, origin/dev
```

Note that I've added the `origin/` names.  These are your Git's way of remembering what your Git *thinks* is set up in the GitHub repository over on GitHub.  Your Git can only update these in certain cases.  The most common case is when using `git fetch`, but even here it gets a bit complicated.

If you did the merge *in your repository*, though, here's what you'll have, assuming you allow `git merge` to do a *fast-forward* (which is its default):

```
          C1   <-- b1, dev, origin/b1
         /
...--G--H   <-- b2, origin/dev
```

Let's return to your own commands, as you've described them:

> After 1 month I worked on a **branch b2**,

If we start with the drawing above, without any updates to it—which is all we can do given your description at this point—then `b2` still points to commit `H`, which still has file `f1.txt` in it.

> made a commit (**c2**)

Presumably you did not touch `f1.txt` in this commit, so it has the *same* `f1.txt` in the new commit:

```
          C1   <-- b1, [dev?], origin/b1
         /
...--G--H   <-- [dev?], origin/dev
         \
          C2   <-- b2
```

Note that I don't know which commit *your* `dev` selects, nor whether *their* (origin's) `dev` still selects commit `H` or not.

> and did (**git pull origin/dev --rebase**).

We now have to get into some of the gory details of `git fetch`.  When you run `git pull`, with or without the `--rebase` option, `git pull` passes *most* of your arguments on to `git fetch`.  The `--rebase` option, however, is an option to `git pull` to tell it *which second command to run*, so it does not pass that one on to `git fetch`.

Let's add this to the mix too:

> I mostly do (**git pull --rebase**)

So one of these two will run:

```
git fetch origin/dev
```

and one of these will run:

```
git fetch
```

#### The gory details about `git fetch`

When you run `git fetch` with *no additional arguments*, as in:

```
git fetch
```

(as you'd get with `git pull --rebase` for instance), your Git will:

1. call up the other Git over at `origin`, using the URL stored under the name `origin`;
2. have them list out *all* their branch names, and for each of those branch names, find out any new names and/or commits they have that you don't;
3. bring over, and stuff into your repository, *all* of those new-to-you names and commits;
4. update *all* your `origin/*` names based on what got brought over in step 3.

Any branch names they *deleted* won't show up in step 2, so won't be updated in step 3, so your Git won't delete the corresponding `origin/` name in your own repository.  That is, supposed they *had* a branch `temporary`, and you ran `git fetch`.  You'd get an `origin/temporary` at this time.  Later, they *delete* their `temporary`.  You run `git fetch`, and your Git sees no `temporary`.  But this just means your Git doesn't update your `origin/temporary`.  So it sticks around from earlier, even though there's no point to its existence any more.  Usually this doesn't matter much, it just means that "stale" names accumulate.<sup>2</sup>

So `git fetch` by itself means *get everything and update all my remote-tracking names, then stop there*.  That's pretty often *exactly what I want*, so it's what I normally use—I almost never use `git pull` at all myself.  I like to see what got updated, see the new branch names if there are any, and maybe take a look at new commits that came in.

But, if you like `git pull`, remember that `git pull origin dev` means *run `git fetch origin dev`*.  Remember that `git pull origin/dev` means *run `git fetch origin/dev`.

The latter doesn't work!  You said that's what you ran, and if that's what you ran, that would explain why it didn't work.  The first non-option word after `git fetch` is the *name of the remote*.  The only remote you have is (probably<sup>3</sup>) `origin`.  There's no `origin/dev` remote, and `git fetch origin/dev` will thus fail.

**This might have been a typo** and maybe you ran `git pull origin dev`.  That would run `git fetch origin dev`.  Running this tells your Git: *call up the other Git over at `origin`, and list out some or all of their branch names, but I'm only really interested in the one spelled `dev`.*  They'll list their names and your Git will see if they have a `dev`.  If so, they'll find out which commit their `dev` has as its most recent commit.

If that commit is new to you—i.e., if they have a `dev` and it has new-to-your commits—your Git will bring those commits over.  In any case, whether or not they have new-to-you commits, your Git will write their most-recent-`dev`-commit hash ID into `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.  If your Git version is at least 1.8.2, your Git will also update your `origin/dev` now, but if your Git is older than that, your Git will fail to update your `origin/dev`.

Once your `git fetch` finishes, it will return "success" if:

- it was able to look up the remote;
- it was able to connect to that Git; and
- it was able to find the right hash ID, and bring over any new commits if needed.

Otherwise your `git fetch` tells your `git pull` that it failed, and your pull stops at this point.  So `git fetch origin/dev` would fail and would stop your rebase at this point.

If that was a typo and you actually ran `git pull origin dev --rebase` (not `git pull origin/dev --rebase`), *then* your `git fetch` probably worked (GitHub's computers are almost always up and working) and you probably got a `.git/FETCH_HEAD` with the right hash ID in it.

*In that case*, your Git will run `git rebase hash-ID`, using the hash ID found in `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.  This will conduct a `git rebase` as shown above, using the hash ID of *their* `dev` commit.

---

<sup>2</sup>If you want to get rid of these "stale" remote-tracking names, use `git fetch --prune` or `git remote prune origin`.  I usually want my Git software to do this automatically every time; to make your Git do that, use `git config --global fetch.prune true`.  Just be aware that this makes your Git remove remote-tracking names as soon as it realizes that they are gone!

<sup>3</sup>You will set up one *remote* per other-Git-repository that you need to talk to regularly.  When you use `git clone` to make an initial clone, that sets up one remote ("the other Git repository that I cloned") and calls it `origin`.  That's the one remote that almost everyone has in almost every repository.

---

#### Returning to your problem once again

> The file **f1.txt** is still there in **branch b2**.

What we need to know, now, is:

- How did you do this merge, in which repository?
- Was the `git rebase` you showed correct, in which case it failed, or did you show us a typo, and the one you *ran* was correct and the one you *showed* was wrong?
- If a rebase ran, what hash ID was stored in their `dev`?  What was in the commit(s) there?

You can run:

```
git fetch origin
git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
```

to get a Git-drawn diagram of the commit graph along with both your and their names for the various commits, and that will tell us more.